# How to add weka features in a new algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, weka

I want to add a new algorithm to weka with features of classification, clustering, association etc in one algo. How should I write a code to include all the weka features and add a tab to weka for this new algorithm.
I have added a dummy algorithm to weka and it works now I want to add an algorithm which has combination of features of weka.

Thanks

Comment: This same question was asked by another AudioQuery at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255989/how-to-add-new-algorithm-to-weka.  1st, why are there 2 AudioQuery users?  Second, why was the first question closed, but this one was seen fit to remain open?  (I actually think both are legitimate questions).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a new algorithm in Weka, have a look at the Weka Manual ( http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index.html )

In the part IV - Appendix, you have the chapter *Extending Weka* and inside the part *Writing a new Classifier*. Very basically, you have to extend a Classifier like `AbstractClassifier` or `RandomizableClassifier`.

In the case of clustering algorithms look at the part Other Algorithms. You will have to extend, for instance, the class `weka.clusterers.AbstractClusterer`.

But, if you want to use existing algorithms in your own program, have a look to this link: http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+WEKA%27s+classes+in+my+own+code%3F