# how to use Gower's Distance for KNN in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, similarity, knn

Currently I'm working on KNN classification and I am having both categorical and continuous variables in my data set. So I decided to use Gower's distance as a similarity measure for KNN. But gower's distance is not available in weka for KNN classification. Is there a way to use Gower's distance for KNN using weka? If it is possible, how can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check how similar algorithms are implemented in Weka. I would suggest to take a look at how [EuclideanDistance](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.6/weka/core/EuclideanDistance.java) is implemented.

Based on that you can now create your preferred algorithm.

Finally, you have to add your new functionality in Weka. To achieve that you have to check the manual. For more details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468038/how-to-add-weka-features-in-a-new-algorithm) and [here](http://weka-addnewalgorithm.blogspot.gr/)